# ubuntu 18.04 boot error cpuFreq:Cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for Cpu 0

Tags: boot, 18.04, error-handling

I am getting the error

```
Ubuntu 18.04 boot error cpuFreq:Cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for Cpu 0
```

Ubuntu18.04 did not start. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: the error is because of space issue, i have cleared the space and now able to login

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem when I try to install ubuntu 18.04 in vmware v12.5.2
I had a solution by turning off 3D Acceleration.
In vmware, select VM. Select Display. Uncheck 'Accelerate 3D graphics' in '3D graphics'
And reboot and then this problem will be passed.